# Why can't scalac optimize tail recursion in certain scenarios?

Tags: performance, scala, tail-recursion, scalac

Why doesn't scalac (the [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) compiler) optimize tail recursion?

Code and compiler invocations that demonstrates this:

```
> cat foo.scala 
class Foo {
 def ifak(n: Int, acc: Int):Int = {  
   if (n == 1) acc  
   else ifak(n-1, n*acc)  
 }
}

> scalac foo.scala
> jd-gui Foo.class
import scala.ScalaObject;

public class Foo
  implements ScalaObject
{
  public int ifak(int n, int acc)
  {
    return ((n == 1) ? acc : 
      ifak(n - 1, n * acc));
  }
}
```

Comment: note that JVM-level tailcall optimisation is contributed for java 7 see http://wikis.sun.com/display/mlvm/TailCalls

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Methods that can be overridden can NOT be tail recursive.  Try this:

```
class Foo {
  private def ifak(n: Int, acc: Int): Int = {  
    if (n == 1) acc  
    else ifak(n-1, n*acc)  
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 What's the rationale? ( I mean I can imagine it , but I would like to know )

Comment: @OscarRyz: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785502/why-wont-the-scala-compiler-apply-tail-call-optimization-unless-a-method-is-fina

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Foo {
  def ifak(n: Int, acc: Int):Int = {
    if (n == 1) acc
    else ifak(n-1, n*acc)
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  override def ifak(n: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
    println("Bar!")
    super.ifak(n, acc)
  }
}

val foobar = new Bar
foobar.ifak(5, 1)
```

Notice that `ifak` *may* be recursive, but it may not as well. Mark the class or the method final, and it shall probably made tail-recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Inner functions are also eligible for TCO.