# Scala and tail recursion

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

There are various answers on Stack Overflow which explain the conditions under which tail recursion is possible in [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29). I understand the limitations and how and where I can take advantage of tail recursion. The part I don't understand is why the limitation to private or final methods exists.

I haven't researched how the Scala compiler actually converts a recursive function to a non-recursive one at a bytecode level, but let's assume it does something like the following. I have a class `Foo` with a recursive function `mod`:

```
class Foo {
  def mod(value: Int, denom: Int): Int = {
    if(denom <= 0 || value <= 0) 0
    else if(0 <= value && value < denom) value
    else mod(value - denom, denom)
  }
}
```

That's a basic modulo function which I imagine the Scala compiler translates to some kind of pseudo-Java-Scala like:

```
class Foo {
  def mod(value: Int, denom: Int): Int = {
    if(denom <= 0 || value <= 0) return 0
    while(value > denom) value -= denom
    return value
  }
}
```

(I can believe I've messed up that translation but I don't think the details are important..)

So now suppose I subclass `Foo`:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  def mod(value:Int, denom: Int): Int = 1
}
```

What it is that stops this from working? When the JVM has a `Foo/Bar` and `mod` is called on it, why is there a problem with resolving the `mod` function that should be used. Why is this any different from the situation where the base function is non-recursive?

A few possible reasons I can see for this being the case are:

1. for whatever reason the implementation of the Scala compiler doesn't handle this (fair enough if that is the case. If so, are there plans to change this?)
2. in `Foo` the `mod` function is munged to `mod-non-recursive` during compilation so `Foo` doesn't actually have a `mod` method to override.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have just answered that, but let's take your own example. Say you defined that class Foo, and made it available as a JAR file.

Then I get that Jar file, and extend your Foo this way:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  def mod(value:Int, denom: Int): Int = {
    Logger.log("Received mod with "+value+" % "+denom)
    super.mod(value, denom)
}
```

Now, when Foo's `mod` calls itself, because my object is a `Bar`, not a `Foo`, you are supposed (and do) go to *Bar's* `mod`, not to Foo's.

And because that is true, you can't optimize it the way you have shown.

It is the CONTRACT of subclassing that, when a super class calls a method on itself, if that method has been overridden it will be the subclass' method to be invoked.

Declaring the method private, making it final, or the class -- or even making a recursive function instead of a method, all insure you won't potentially have to go to a subclass implementation.

Answer (score -1):

IttayD just asked this question earlier today. The answer is that Foo's tail recursion will only be optimized if [you can't override mod in subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699376/why-doesnt-scalac-optimize-tail-recursion) (be that becuase the class is final, or because the method is final or private.)

Comment: @Ken Bloom: ams knows that methods must be final or private or optimization won't occur.  He's asking *why* that is.  Why is it that scalac doesn't optimize overridable methods?  It's not like there's any ambiguity in this implementation of mod -- recursive calls in this implementation will always call this implementation.

Comment: Not true. If the function [i]might[/i] be overridden, the code generated for calling must be polymorphic. Consider that in that case you don't know that the first call came from a subclass and not from "outside" the class in which that method is defined.

Comment: @Ken - the OP says quite clearly that he understands the limitations (i.e. private/final) - he wants to understand the reasons behind it