# Tail call optimization throwing error on simple function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I have a simple method to build a tree:

```
    @tailrec final def buildTree (X:DenseMatrix[Double], Y:DenseVector[Double], minBucket:Int):Node = {
        // Get the split variable, split point and data 
        val (splitVar, splitPoint, leftX, leftY, rightX, rightY) = chooseSplit(X, Y, minBucket);
        // If we couldn't find a split, then we have a leaf
        if(splitVar == Double.NegativeInfinity){
            new Node(Y)
        }else{
            // Otherwise recursively build the children and create yourself as a vertex
            val left = buildTree(leftX, leftY, minBucket)
            val right = buildTree(rightX, rightY, minBucket)
            new Node(Y, splitVar, splitPoint, left, right)
        }
```

However, when I go to compile, I get: 
`could not optimize @tailrec annotated method buildTree: it contains a recursive call not in tail position`

I've done things like this in OCaml without any problem at all. Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785502/why-wont-the-scala-compiler-apply-tail-call-optimization-unless-a-method-is-fin).

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is pretty clear: your method is neither `private` nor `final`, therefore it can be overridden, therefore it is not guaranteed that the calls to `buildTree` will go to the same method. The method needs to be either `private` or `final`.

But even if it *were* `private` or `final`, the recursive calls are not in tail position.

Basically, your tail recursive call is neither a tail call nor even guaranteed to be recursive.

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice that it's not even theoretically tail recursive.

Comment: I've updated the question. This works *without any issues* in OCaml. My question is how to get scala to perform the optimization (which is not that complicated).

Comment: Well, the strategies for making something tail recursive are well known: add an accumulator, convert to continuation-passing-style, use trampolines, …

Comment: @dave When you say it "works without any issues in OCaml, do you mean that OCaml automatically converts your non-tail-recursive function to a version that is tail-recursive? Your function is not tail recursive as written.

Comment: @dfan, I'm not entirely sure, hence the question. I know that the function isn't properly tail recursive but more mature, non JVM crippled languages can still make the optimization.

Comment: What optimization? It's not tail recursive, and doesn't make tail calls. What do you think OCaml is optimising, exactly?