# Why is this method causing a StackOverflowError?

Tags: scala, recursion

The method in the class below assumes that `y` is positive:

```
class Calculator {
  def addPos(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
    if (y == 0) x
    else {
      val temp: Int = x + 1
      if (temp < x) throw new OverflowException
      else addPos(temp, y - 1)
    }
  }
}
```

It is tail recursive and adds one to `x` from `y` in each recursion until `y` is 0. It also throws when be exceed `Int.MaxValue`. I know that there is a far simpler implementation of this function that doesn't need recursion, BUT, I want to find out why this method causes a StackOverflowError when I do:

```
val newCalc = new Calculator
println(newCalc.addPos(0, Int.MaxValue))
```

I thought that since it's tail recursive, the method could not cause an SOError.

Comment: Can you paste a stack trace? Does it compile when you add the `@tailrec` annotation?

Comment: I thought it wouldn't matter that I extracted a method from a class and presented it to you as a function, but apparently it does. So I've updated the question to show what I'm actually running. Please see my edit.

Comment: Interesting. Does it work if you move it into an `object`? Or make it `final`? Other than it getting confused by the potential need for dynamic dispatch I cannot see why it would not work. Does the `@tailrec` annotation compile?

Comment: You'll probably get this error for `@tailrec`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785502/why-wont-the-scala-compiler-apply-tail-call-optimization-unless-a-method-is-fin?rq=1